# Config nginx to listen to all ports

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a flask app deployed in an EC2, configured with nginx/gunicorn3. Security group in the EC2 is both(inbound and outbound) set in all traffic.

I am having an issue with nginx configuration.

I have set it to listen to port 8080 and it only works on this port (neither port 80 will do).

What I want to do is to hit the domain without the port 8080 and return the desired results. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit question to add the nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to solve the issue: 
1- Change the Nginx configuration to listen on port 80 and expose port 80
2- keep port 8080, but use a load balancer in front of the EC2 node and link the domain name to the load balancer instead of the EC2 node.